# Error al llamar a función: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, html, html5

¿Por qué obtengo el siguiente error al llamar a mi función `have_posts`?:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function have_posts() in /home/mlnbwqhe/public_html/index.php on line 3
```

[image]

Comment: te recomiendo editar el titulo de tu pregunta, además lee [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta, recuerda que muchos somos un poco ciego o lo estamos viendo desde nuestro movil por lo que la imagen no nos seré util, mejor es publicar el código como texto. :)

Comment: Disculpa, es que soy nuevo, gracias por la información será mejor para la próxima :)

Comment: ¿por qué esperar una nueva oportunidad?, puedes mejorarlo ahora, solo edita tu pregunta y añade el código. :)

Comment: @gt_150699 Bienvenido a StackOverflow te invito a hacer el [tour] de nuestro sitio podras ganar medallas y aprenderas a usar esta plataforma

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje te está avisando de que no encuentra la función `have_posts`

La función debería estar definida en ese mismo php, o encontrarse en algún otro php al que le hacemos un [require](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php)/[include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

Otra opción es que desde otro php externo donde esté definida la función se haga un include/require del php que estás mostrando.

En cualquiera de los casos, la función debe existir en algún sitio y ser accesible.

Comment: si bien tu pregunta puede ayudar al usuario , se trata de evitar preguntas [mal formadas te invito a leer Como Responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)